# Vuetify Nuxt.js : how to add url link in image tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

i am new in Nuxt.js and Vuetifiy i want to add url link in image tag. if i press image it should open other page link

**my page layout**

[image]
**i have specified urls each image have different url like i want to add this url to image**

```
to="/AppMain/Support/Support" 
and
 to="/UserDash/Profile" 
also
 to="/AppMain/Entertainment"
 how to add this urls in image
```

my code

```html
    <template>
      <v-layout style="width: auto;" class="ma-auto">
        <v-carousel cycle light height="309" hide-delimiter-background show-arrows-on-hover>
          <v-carousel-item v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :key="i">
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="3" v-for="(images, j) in slide.images" :key="j">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center">
                  <v-img :src="images.src" width="30"/>
                  <span class="mx-auto text-center caption">{{ images.caption }}</span>
                </div>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-carousel-item>
        </v-carousel>
      </v-layout>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "playground",
      data: () => ({
        slides: [
          {
            images: [
              { src: "https://akam.cdn.jdmagicbox.com/images/icontent/newwap/newprotmore/hkm_allcategories.svg", caption: "All Categories"},
              { src: "https://akam.cdn.jdmagicbox.com/images/icontent/newwap/newprotmore/hkm_b2b.svg", caption: "B2B" },
              { src: "https://akam.cdn.jdmagicbox.com/images/icontent/newwap/newprotmore/hkm_shopping.svg", caption: "Shopping" }
              
            ]
          },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it:

Use `<nuxt-link />`:

```html
<nuxt-link to="#">
  <v-img :src="images.src" width="30"/>
</nuxt-link>
```

If you add the urls to the `slide.images` array, you can dynamically assign them:

```html
<nuxt-link :to="images.url">
```

Comment: is there possible to you answer my another question regarding nuxt.js image uploading please reply

Comment: @user12380208 what's the question url?

Comment: thank you for replying my question url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182413/how-to-make-image-uploading-form-in-nuxt-js-using-laravel-backend-api?noredirect=1#comment113501637_64182413 in this question i am not added image file input for better under stand of my question. thank you

Comment: this is not working with nuxtjs3 and vuetify3  : <NuxtLink to="/" ><v-img src="/images/logo.png"/></NuxtLink> where logo is in public folder

Comment: @cyril what is the error?

Comment: no error, just nothing appears :/